# Xcode Universal Storyboard Size

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

What's the size in pixels of the universal storyboard in Xcode? I want to create a custom design in Photoshop so I need to know the size for the universal storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the storyboard size is 600x600px but you should not rely on this. Usually you create a design in 640 x 1136px (@2X resolution) and then create icons for each resolution (@1X, @2X - our base, @3X). DPI resolution doesn't matter is this case, just use default DPI 72.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) you can find resolutions for various iOS device.

Comment: So I can design my app interface in 640 x 1136??

Comment: yes, of course. After you're done with the design you will need to resize it to 1X (320 x 568) and 3X (960 X 1704).  By doing so you will get 3 required resolutions for the iOS app.

Comment: Sorry for asking alot. But I'm new to universal storyboards. So I need 3 images of every button and so on? And how do I tell xcode which is which?

Comment: Exactly. You use asset catalogue to handle different icon resolutions (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html). XCode will then take automatically the proper icon image.

Comment: I usually use a Mac app called "Prepo" on the App Store to create 1x 2x and 3x images.

Comment: Okay thanks alot guys! I think I can figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking about designing the views in your app, right? You should not design to the universal storyboard size of 600x600 because there will never be a 600x600 device. You should instead design for you target devices. Focus your design around points rather than pixels. Unless you are working on really high end graphics, your app will be built in points.

I design everything based on the iPhone 6 and then allow for some variability in the layouts for the iPhone 6 Plus and the iPhone 5 and then finally the iPhone 4 (as an after thought--just squeeze everything in). iPad layouts (sorry about this) are last on the list.

Here's a great chart showing all of the device sizes: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions